# External monitor looks fine, but built-in laptop display has small font everywhere and slightly blurry

Tags: display, fonts, display-resolution

Even when my laptop is not connected to the external monitor, the font, and everything really looks small, zoomed-out, and a bit blurry.

The resolution is set correctly.

Is there a way to fix this?

I can play around with font size but some stuff such as the top bars of windows, tabs in Chrome and the overall look of the desktop looks off.

Laptop display: 1920 x 1080 14"

Monitor: 1920 x 1080 24"

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: @K7AAY I have edited the post, thank you. Let me know if theres any other information that might help